# How to select lines based on column values and transform the lines in a specific way in a large dataframe in R

Tags: r, database, search, replace

I am trying to select and transform some lines in a dataframe in R, based on a very specific criteria, but I'm not too sure where to start. So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    ID    t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10 gr1 gr2 gr3 gr4
    1     0  0  1  0  0  0  2  2  0  0   1   0   0   0
    2     1  0  0  0  2  0  2  2  2  2   0   1   0   0
    3     1  1  1  2  0  2  2  1  2  0   0   1   0   0
    4     0  0  0  1  2  2  1  1  1  0   0   0   0   1
    5     2  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   1   0
```

t columns are for time, or re-encounter occasion of each animal (unique ID#).

gr columns are for the group to which an animal belongs.

the data under the time columns define states in which an animal is encountered at time t.

In my dataframe I have animals that go from state 2 to state 1, which is normal and I want to keep it like this. However, I also have animals that go from state 1 to state 2, which I can't have in the program I'm using to analyse my data. So what I would like to do is to create a "dummy" individual for every individual that goes from 1 to 2 and separate the encounter history in 2.

The first thing I need is to keep all the data in the original line up until I reach the time where there is a 2, replace this 2 by a 1, and replace the rest of the history with 0s. I also need to change the value of the group identifier to -1 instead of one. All this only for histories that go from 1 to 2, not the others i.e. if I have histories that go from 2 to 1, I want them to be left as is (e.g. ID#5).

Next, I need to create a new line with a x' identifier that will contain 0s for the start of the history, up until the switch from 1 to 2 (so at the timestep of the first 2), but will contain the rest of the capture history, and put a 1 in the same group as the original line. If the switch from 2 to 1 happens more than once, then repeat the transformation in the same way. So basically I want to take this:

```
    ID    t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10 gr1 gr2 gr3 gr4
    1     0  0  1  0  0  0  2  2  0  0   1   0   0   0
```

and make it into this:

```
    ID    t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10 gr1 gr2 gr3 gr4
    1     0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   -1  0   0   0
    1'    0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0   1   0   0   0
```

So if applied to the whole dataframe, I would like to take this:

```
    ID    t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10 gr1 gr2 gr3 gr4
    1     0  0  1  0  0  0  2  2  0  0   1   0   0   0
    2     1  0  0  0  2  0  2  2  2  2   0   1   0   0
    3     1  1  1  2  0  2  2  1  2  0   0   1   0   0
    4     0  0  0  1  2  2  1  1  1  0   0   0   0   1
    5     2  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   1   0
```

And make it into this:

```
    ID    t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10 gr1 gr2 gr3 gr4
    1     0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   -1  0   0   0
    1'    0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0   1   0   0   0
    2     1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   -1  0   0
    2'    0  0  0  0  2  0  2  2  2  2   0   1   0   0
    3     1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   -1  0   0
    3'    0  0  0  2  0  2  2  1  1  0   0   -1  0   0
    3''   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0   0   1   0   0
    4     0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   -1
    4'    0  0  0  0  2  2  1  1  1  0   0   0   0   1
    5     2  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   1   0
```

I know this is quite comlpicated, and I see how I need to separate the different steps, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the first step going i.e. searching for the right lines in the dataframe. The challenge comes from the fact that the 1 and following 2 can be in an adjacent column, or have a bunch of 1 and/or 0 in between them.

Anyway, thanks a lot for the help, and if there is anything I can do to make the text/title clearer please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work, there is probably a more eleguant way of doing this but this works:

```
 ### YOUR DATA
   data <- data.frame(ID=c(1:5),t1=c(0,1,1,0,2),t2=c(0,0,1,0,0),t3=c(1,0,1,0,0),t4=c(0,0,2,1,1),t5=c(0,2,0,2,0),t6=c(0,0,2,2,0),t7=c(2,2,2,1,1),t8=c(2,2,1,1,0),t9=c(0,2,2,1,0),t10=c(0,2,0,0,0),gr1=c(1,0,0,0,0),gr2=c(0,1,1,0,0),gr3=c(0,0,0,0,1),gr4=c(0,0,0,1,0))



for(i in 1:length(data$ID)){

    bg = which(data[i,2:11]==2)+1    ### Where is there 2?
    bg = ifelse(length(bg) == 0,0,min(bg)) ###prevent NA and take 1st occurence of 2
    bgg = which(data[i,bg:11]==2) ### Where is there 2 after the first 2?
    bgg = c((ifelse(bgg == 0,0,bgg+(bg-1)))) ### Prevent NA 
mn = as.numeric(which.max(data[i,2:bg]==1))+1  ### Last one before 2


 if((mn-bg) < 0){
     ### ------- SECOND TASK ------### 
     ### Keep the task in this order if you wanna keep the original history after the 2  


        n<-nrow(data)+i   ### Define a new row 
        data[n,] = data[i,]   ### Paste the data 
        data[n,2:mn] = 0   ### Put zero before the 2
        data[n,1] = paste(i,"'")   ### Name the ID'

    ###------- FIRST TASK -----#### 

       data[i,bgg] = 0     ### DAta after the 2 become 0
       data[i,bg] = 1      ### the 2 become 1
       data$change[i] = "yes"  ### Keep history of change

    while(sum(data[i,12:15])>0){
        data[i,12] = data[i,12] * -1   ### Negative if change
        data[i,13] = data[i,13] * -1   
        data[i,14] = data[i,14] * -1 
        data[i,15] = data[i,15] * -1 
    }}

  else if((mn-bg)>=0){
       data$change[i] = "no"   ### Keep history of no change
     }
   }


dummies<-subset(data, data$change=="yes")
```

Hope it is what you want :)

Lemmings for the win

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `match` is what you will need in that it will return the index at which given value occurs. E.g.

```
> match(1, c(0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,1))
[1] 4
> match(2, c(0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,1))
[1] 6
```

I can edit this reply as we work on more tailored solution.

Assume `d` is your data frame, to find instances where 1 occurs before 2:

```
for (rid in 1:nrow(d)){

  # Get index of group that the ID is from 
  grpid <- 11 + match(1,d[rid, 12:15])
  # If position of 1 is less than position of 2
  if (match(1, d[rid, 2:11]) < match(2, d[rid, 2:10]){
    d[rid, grpid] <- -1
  }
```

}

Comment: I imagine that could work, but in the actual dataframe I have 108 time steps and 87 000 individuals... so it would be a little unpractical to have to write each history by hand... Or maybe its simply me and I dont see how to automate the match function without having to write down the whole history.. And also the idea is to have it recognize when there are 1s occuring before 2s, in that order so I don't know if that would work.

Comment: I added example on how to iterate over all rows and determine if `1 < 2`, then set `grpid` to `-1`.

Comment: I added you to the following chatroom. I am happy to discuss how best to solve your issue there: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141379/match-rows

Comment: Thanks for the help man, it took me a while to get it sorted out but the loop below works :)